# Verify that partition is encrypted

Tags: debian, partition, lvm, encryption

I just installed Debian and as far as I can remember I encrypted my home-partition using LVM. During the boot process I haven't been asked to enter the password.

Is there any way to check whether the encryption is up and running?

Comment: Please paste the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: please share the output of  `dmsetup table` command

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what the OP was looking for.

```
lsblk | grep 'crypt'
```

or bash scripting:

```
#!/bin/bash
is_encrypted=$(lsblk | grep 'crypt')
if [ -n "${is_encrypted}" ]; then
  echo "Found disk encryption is set: ${is_encrypted}"
  return 0
else
  echo "No disk encryption partition is found!"
  return 1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

LVM isn't a type of encryption. It's something different than partitions. For more information visit [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM%20Arch%20Wiki).

Comment: LVM has also a crypt target, but this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You can put encrypted disk in LVM. So you can put an encrypted disk in LVM (That's what the OP said).